# Use of window object in my component causing error after working at first

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to use a window event to add a background to my nav on scroll. At first, it worked. Now, I am not able to build and getting the following error in the console:

"Uncaught TypeError: doc.documentElement.doScroll is not a function at ready.js: 19 at ready.js: 7 at Object../node_modules/@mikaelkristiansson/domready.ready.js..."

I have tried, as some have suggested in regards to using window objects in Gatsby, to move my scroll function arguments to the ComponentDidMount lifecycle method. That has not fixed the issue. I have seen that there is an issue in using the window object in SSGs like Gatsby but I am not understanding how to work around this issue.

This is the relevant parts of my code on this:

```
    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);

    }

   handleScroll = () => {
        let position = window.scrollY;
        this.setState({scrolled: position})
    }
```

and the JSX code which uses the scrolled value in state to apply the background:

```
    <StyledNavbar style={this.state.showMenu || this.state.scrolled > 0 ? 
    {'background':'var(--Black)', 'opacity': '0.85', 'transition': '0.5s ease- 
    in-out'}: {'background': 'transparent'}} >
```

Comment: Update: weird behavior. I changed the "scroll" in the lifecycle events to "onScroll" thinking that there may be a clash with the node module I am using. I am not able to build the page as expected when not viewing the developer tools in Chrome. I still get the error when I am looking at the page with dev tools open...

Comment: This issue seems to be a Chrome issue as I am not seeing the same problem in Firefox. Both are the latest version.

Comment: Try what is suggested here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/#how-to-check-if-window-is-defined

Comment: Try wrapping code that references `window` with a conditional:
`if (typeof window !== `undefined`) { ... }`